# Turning off a section of code in html with something like an if statement

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I have a live site and I have to keep working on it on a live site, which means I am viewing the page a lot.

I am wondering if there is a way of using like an if statement in HTML that I can turn off the google analytic's code so it doesn't mess up our reports?  So I can simply change a value on the page (like a TRUE/FALSE) so I can work on it to my hearts content and I don't ruin the analytics.

Comment: Why not just comment out the analytics code?

Comment: As it is live that can't be done of course, if they did, they would loose all user stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better approach is to have Google analytics filter out your IP address.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Check window.location.search for a querystring variable and set that variable when you don't want the analytics. Below shows code for hiding only when querystring contains hidegoogle=yes

```
var hide = window.location.search.match(/hidegoogle=(yes|no)/);

if (hide !== null && hide[1] === "yes") {
    console.log('yes');
} else {
    console.log('no');
    // Run analytics here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Google Tag Manager:

http://tagmanager.google.com/

It can manage Google Analytics Tags.